# Is there an efficient implementation for quantifying the similarity between two Strings?

Tags: java, string, levenshtein-distance

Let's say I have several very long Strings consisting of completely random characters. I aim to represent their similarity to one designated master String in a number.

For example: 12345 is very similar 23456, but not so similar to 12abcdef

Assuming Java, is there already an efficient implementation for such an algorithm?
For example I think this would probably do what I want: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance
but I need something very efficient for super-long Strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if there is a java implementation for it, but you can find the implementation for your algorithm here:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#Java

good luck :)

Comment: Thanks, I used that, also your answer was first ;)

Answer (score 2):

The standard way is [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

There is an implementation in [Apache commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/): [`StringUtils.getLevenshteinDistance()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#getLevenshteinDistance%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Answer (score 1):

"Efficient" is unfortunately unprecise. Efficient in terms of what ? Time ? Memory ? And regards to what "quality" of similarity measure ?

Ask yourself first what similarity you want, for what purpose, with which kind of permutations/replacement allowed, etc, then you will be able to search for a "*-efficient" algorithm that computes the metrics which is adapted to your needs

you can start by [this paper](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/Web/People/wcohen/postscript/kdd-2003-match-ws.pdf) or [this post](http://www.joyofdata.de/blog/comparison-of-string-distance-algorithms/) to see the differences, or search for "string similarity metrics" on Google.

Answer (score 0):

Googling seems to come up with lots of potential solutions for you. For example, you can try this one:

https://github.com/joewandy/BioinfoApp/blob/master/src/com/joewandy/bioinfoapp/model/stringDistance/LevenshteinDistance.java